# errors and projection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

For the problem of projections, for the 1-d case, say we have some line $a$ through the origin, and a vector $v$, not on $a$. The projection of $v$ onto $a$ is some multiple $x$ of a: $p = xa$, and the error between the vector $v$ and $p$ is $e = v - xa$. The closest point to the line that $v$ can be projected on will end up forming a right angle if one were to draw a line from $v$ to that point $p$ so we can say $a^Te = 0$ or equivalently $a^T(v - xa) = 0$.

We can do the same for matrices and end up with $A^T(v - Ax) = 0$. Now here is the question algebraiclly I can see why in the 1-d case we transpose $a$ in $a^Te = 0$, because we want that to be a scalar, otherwise we would have $ae = Z$, some matrix $Z$, (which maybe will just be an all zero matrix? I'm not sure).

However for matrices, if the statement is "the error is orthogonal to the column space of $A$", $A^Te = 0$ instead seems to be telling me that it's orthogonal to the row space of $A$. I guess the question can be simplified to, why do we multiply by $A^T$ in $A^T(v - Ax) = 0$ instead of $A(v-Ax) =0$, aside from "the algebra works out that way" or "its the only way to multiply $A^TA$ because the dimensions of $AA$ don't work out unless $A$ is square to begin with (we are assuming $A$ is rectangular).

EDIT: ok upon further reflextion, $A^T(v - Ax) = 0$ is telling me that the vector $v - Ax$ is in the null space of $A^T$, and I know that the null space of $A^T$ and the column space of $A$ are orthogonal, therefor $v - Ax$ is orthogonal to column space of $A$, because it is in the null space of $A^T$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a^Te=0$, you don’t say that the *row* vector $a^T$ is orthogonal to $e$; you say that the *column* vector $a$ is orthogonal to $e$. If you expand $A^Te$ by rows, you’ll find that each element of the product is of the form $a_i^Te$. The rows of $A^T$ are, of course, the columns of $A$, so if $A^Te=0$, then $e$ is orthogonal to each *column* of $A$. By linearity, then, it is also orthogonal to the entire column space.